# random function for final project in tic tac toe

Tags: c#

I don't understand why the messagebox keeps displaying 0.  For each sequence there is a direction.  The purpose of the random function is to find the best point to start a new sequence.  There seems to be a problem with my howfree function, I can't understand what the problem is, please help me.

```
public int howfree(int x, int y)
    {
        int freenum = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (GameForm.direction dirs in (GameForm.direction[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(GameForm.direction)))
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                y += Directions[(int)dirs, 0];
                x += Directions[(int)dirs, 1];
                if ( InBoard(y, x) && cells[y,x].cellType == Type.EMPTY)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            if (counter == 5)
            {
                freenum++;
            }
            counter = 0;
        }
        return freenum;
    }
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    public Cell Randomize()
    {
        int row=0;
        int col=0;
        Random random = new Random();
        int rand = 0;
        //bool Found = false;
        int max = 0;
        int fff=0;
        List<Cell> Options = new List<Cell>();
        foreach (Cell CCC in cells)
        {
            fff=howfree(CCC.row,CCC.col);
            if (fff > max)
                max = fff;
        }
        foreach (Cell c in cells)
        {
            if (howfree(c.row, c.col) == max)
            {
                Options.Add(new Cell(c.row, c.col));
            }
        }

       // while (!Found)
      //  {
            rand = (int)random.NextDouble() * (Options.Count - 1);
            //row = random.Next() * (Settings.Rows);
            //col = random.Next() * (Settings.Cols);
            MessageBox.Show(rand.ToString());
            row = Options[rand].row;
            col = Options[rand].col;
        //}
        return new Cell(row, col);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

```
rand = (int)random.NextDouble() * (Options.Count - 1);
```

Random.NextDouble() will produce number between 0 and less than 1.0.
That means it can get up to 0.999 (You get my point) but will never be 1.

When you use explicit int cast on a fraction less bigger than 0 and less than 1 you will always get 0.

You should have done it like this:

```
rand = (int)(random.NextDouble() * (Options.Count - 1));
```

So now it will int cast after the count of options.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the overload that's designed for integers?

```
rand = random.Next(Options.Count);
```

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5.aspx):

> Returns a nonnegative random integer that is less than the specified maximum.